# App/Extension to monitor a webpage for keywords

Tags: chrome, monitoring

I'm interested in an app that allows users to monitor webpages for the existence of user-specified keywords, and get notified when these keywords are detected. I was originally using VisualPing (to check when Amazon listings went live, for example), but I find myself needing a little more specificity when it comes to checking WHAT is changing. Are there any apps that can do this? I'd prefer something like a Chrome extension or something that can send me an email/text message whenever the first time the keyword is detected (in context). I'm okay with false positives/repeated reports, as I can always just check the site manually myself as well. I can provide a sample use case, if that would help, as well:

site:
https://www.reddit.com/r/mechmarket/new/

keywords: 
"pbt", "spacebar", "pbt spacebar"

Notify on refresh if any of the above is detected. Notice that the webpage updates often, so I can't rely on something like VisualPing, which detects if a space undergoes changes.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you detail why VisualPing does not satisfy you? Describe exactly the features you need. In "*detects if a space undergoes changes*" what do you mean by "space"?

Comment: It's not granular enough; I can't specify how I want it to change. For example, with Amazon, it's easy to draw a box around the area where it says "Currently unavailable" because if that space changes there's a good chance the item will be available again. But for a page that's constantly changing, I'd like more control over HOW it changes, e.g. what keyword shows up upon refresh, so that I'm not spammed with notifications.

Answer (score -1):

Suggest you use the Regex function of [PageMonitor Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/page-monitor/ogeebjpdeabhncjpfhgdibjajcajepgg).

[image]

Disclaimer: My company makes both Visualping and PageMonitor.